# Selenium NoSuchElementException while trying to login to OneDrive web page (different locating elements were tried)

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I am planning on writing a script to automate the login to the OneDrive web page by using Selenium. Google Chrome and Chromedriver Version are both 74. I always run into the NoSuchElementException and do not know why. For other applications other than login I had no problems using Selenium and the Chrome setup.

The html code of the email input field should be the following:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-label="E-Mail, Telefon oder Skype" placeholder="E-Mail, Telefon oder Skype" data-bind="hasFocus: focus, textInput: email, attr: {'placeholder': config.text.emailPlaceHolder,
                            'aria-label': config.text.emailPlaceHolderAria, 'aria-invalid': !error}" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
```

The Code looks as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://onedrive.live.com/about/de-ch/signin/") 
time.sleep(10)

email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div/input")
email.send_keys("test")
```

Above, the XPath was used to locate the html snippet, which was directly copied out of Chrome. This produces the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div/input"}

  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

Other approaches to locate the html snippet were:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_class_name("form-control")
username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control")
```

These also produced the same error.

With what I found online, I am quite sure that this is the correct way.
Might the web page sort of block the automated login?

Thank you very much for your help.

Kind regards
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are trying to access is inside an `iframe`. You need to switch to the frame before you access the elements inside.

Try this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.get("https://onedrive.live.com/about/de-ch/signin/")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME,"SignIn")))

email = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.form-group > input.form-control")))
email.send_keys("test@etst.test")
```

To use WebDriverWait you have to import the followings

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```